# How to specify on sqs to create resources with the count element

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am sorry to ask this question but can anyone tell me what this mean?

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"
  count   = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
```

what does the 1 and 0 represent?

Comment: Count is the count of the resources to create. If it's 0, it will not create the resource.

Comment: Is this supposed to be terraform? If so: you are missing some `{`.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html and https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, count is being used to create resources conditionally. If enabled is true, it creates one resource. If enabled is false, the resource is not created.